# Remove duplicate on JSON iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, for-loop

Need to iterate over the below JSON object to produce a report (Tabular Report in table structure).

Report will basically consist of List of stories & its related tasks state.

```
QueryResults = {
    "Results": [
        {
            "Name" : "Tech Design",
            "State" : "Completed",
            "StoryName" : "FB Integration"
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Development",
            "State" : "In-Progress",
            "StoryName" : "FB Integration"
        },
        {
            "Name" : "QA Testing",
            "State" : "Not Started",
            "StoryName" : "FB Integration"
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Front End Development",
            "State" : "Completed",
            "StoryName" : "FB Integration"
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Tech Design",
            "State" : "Not Started",
            "StoryName" : "Twitter Integration"
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Development",
            "State" : "Not Started",
            "StoryName" : "Twitter Integration"
        }
    ]
}
```

HTML to populate:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>StoryName</td>
        <td>TechDesign</td>
        <td>FED</td>
        <td>QA</td>
        <td>Development</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FB Integration</td>
        <td>Completed</td>
        <td>Completed</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
    </tr>
    ......
    ......
</table>
```

Script :

```
for(var i=0; i < QueryResults.Results.length; i++) {
  data+= '<tr><td>' + QueryResults.Results[i].StoryName + '</td><td>' + QueryResults.Results[i].State + '</td></tr>'; 
}

// it will list down all the story name i.e. same story name multiple times
```

Please provide me pointers to remove the duplicate story names while iterating over the JSON and populate the respective details in other columns.

Comment: What's supposed to happen to the duplicates? Do you want to discard them? If yes, which one do you want to keep?

Comment: We need to pick the task name & status from the duplicate entries and avoid to print the story name to display twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to remove the duplicate entries, you want to merge them per-storyname.

```
var stories = {};
for (var i=0; i<QueryResults.Results.length; i++) {
    var result = QueryResults.Results[i],
        name = result.StoryName
    if (!(name in stories))
        stories[name] = {};
    stories[name][result.Name] = result.State;
}
/* console.log(stories):
{
    "FB Integration":{"Tech Design":"Completed","Development":"In-Progress","QA Testing":"Not Started","Front End Development":"Completed"},
    "Twitter Integration":{"Tech Design":"Not Started","Development":"Not Started"}
} */
```

Now you can build a table from that.

```
var keys = [];
for (var i=0; i<QueryResults.Results.length; i++) {
    var n = QueryResults.Results[i].Name;
    if (keys.indexOf(n) == -1)
         keys.push(n);
}
var data = "<table><tr><th>Story Name</th>";
for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
    data += "<th>"+keys[i]+"</th>";
data += "</tr>";
for (var storyname in stories) {
    data += "<tr><th>"+storyname+"</th>";
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
        data += "<td>"+(stories[storyname][keys[i]] || "n.a.")+"</td>";
    data += "</tr>";
}
data += "</table>";
```

If you want to ensure a particular order or use a custom table header, you of course also could use a static `keys` array:

```
var keys = ["Tech Design","Front End Development","QA Testing","Development"];
var data = "<table><tr><td>StoryName</td><td>TechDesign</td><td>FED</td><td>QA</td><td>Development</td></tr>";
for (storyname in stories) {
…
```

Comment: it is simply awsome. You just resolved thing where i was stuck from last 3 hours. thanks a lot Bergi for detailed code description. something new and refreshing for me with JSON iteration.