# Get cumulative results with json data traversing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

We are traversing JSON object to populate the table data with Predefined header items.

(code from an answer to [this former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678744/remove-duplicate-on-json-iteration))

```
var stories = {};
for (var i=0; i<QueryResults.Results.length; i++) {
    var result = QueryResults.Results[i],
        name = result.StoryName
    if (!(name in stories))
        stories[name] = {};
    stories[name][result.Name] = result.State;
}

var keys = ['QA Cycle 1', 'QA Cycle 2', 'Development - GUI', 'Development - Backend'];

var data = "<table><tr><th>Story Name</th><th colspan='2'>Quality Assuance</th><th colspan='2'>Development</th></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td>";
for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
    data += "<th>"+keys[i]+"</th>";
data += "</tr>";
for (var storyname in stories) {
    data += "<tr><th>"+storyname+"</th>";
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
        data += "<td>"+(stories[storyname][keys[i]] || "n.a.")+"</td>";
    data += "</tr>";
}
data += "</table>";

$('body').append(data);
```

As of now, every task has a state like "Defined","In-Progress","Complete" & "Not Applicable.

Now, i want to merge two subtasks "Development - GUI" & "Development - Backend" into one main task "Development" and then insert a cumulative state by calculating on following rules:

- Under Development task, if first subtask has state "Completed" and  second has "Defined" then result will be "In-Progress".
- If any of the subtask has "NA" state and cumulative result will become "NA"

By doing this, second row[i.e subtasks] will be removed from table and cumulative results will render for main task column.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/a5HRu/4/

Any suggestions or help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this:

```
var keys = ['QA Cycle 1', 'QA Cycle 2', 'Development'];

…
for (var storyname in stories) {
    var story = stories[storyname];

    // variables for shortening the code
    var sub1 = story['Development - GUI'],
        sub2 = story['Development - Backend'],
        main = 'Development';

    if (sub1 && sub2) { // neither is NA
        if (sub1 == sub2)
            story[main] = sub1;
        else if (sub1=="Completed" && sub2=="Defined")
            story[main] = "In-Progress";
        else
            story[main] = "unknown subtask state combination";
    }
    data += "<tr><th>"+storyname+"</th>";
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
        data += "<td>"+(story[keys[i]] || "n.a.")+"</td>";
    data += "</tr>";
}
…
```

Comment: do i need to write a separate variables set if column merge needed for "QA Cycle 1" & "Qa Cycle 2" under "Quality"? or is there any better approach to do the same? Because, i may encounter more of such column merges in future updates. Please suggest. Tried the same in this fiddle-: jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/a5HRu/6

Comment: Of course you could generalize the idea. Just make a collection of merges, and loop over them applying the logic for each one.